# Grid view showing wrong item clicked in android

Tags: android

I have three columns in a list view like gridview .Whenever i click an item, the corresponding first item of that particular row is shown. I have checked the position in onitemclick listener, it shows the position of 1 st item clicked. Like in fist row the position is 0, 2nd 3, 3rd 6. 4th 9 and so on....
Can anyone please help me out

Comment: Please show us some code so we can help you

Comment: are you using some kind of custom GridView ?